It is possible to use 'google-cloud/logging' in local with the firebase emulator?
When I try to log  locally using the Firebase Emulator with GCP logging, I can't use logging from the library @google-cloud/logging. If I use console.log(), it works fine. I have already tried deploying the function, and logging with @google-cloud/logging works, just not locally.
I get the following warning when I try to run 'log.write(entry)', and nothing appear in the fb emulator logs tab :

functions: Finished "us-central1-pubsubTriggeredFunction" in 4.393208ms
⚠ External network resource requested!
URL: "http://169.254.169.252/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone"
Be careful, this may be a production service.

My function code :
async function logExecutionInfos(severity, message, functionName,
    event = null, errCode = null, errBody = null) {
    const slash = '%2F';
    const logName = 'test{slash}first${slash}${globalStore.getFirstId()}';
    const log = logging.log(logName);

    const metadata = new Metadata(functionName, message, severity);
    const payload = new Payload();

    payload.setRideId(globalStore.getRideId());
    payload.setPubsubMessageId(globalStore.getMessageId());
    message ? payload.setMessage(message) : null;
    event   ? payload.setEvent(event) : null;
    errCode ? payload.setErrorCode(errCode) : null;
    errBody ? payload.setErrorBody(errBody) : null;

    const entry = log.entry(metadata.getMetadata(), payload.getPayload());
    log.write(entry);
}

I have already tried setting up with a service account but still nothing:
// Path to your service account key file
const serviceAccountPath = path.join(__dirname, '../test-app-firebase-952e06254be0.json');
// Load the service account key file
const serviceAccount = require(serviceAccountPath);

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    serviceAccountId:  serviceAccount.client_email
});
const db = admin.firestore();
const logging = new Logging({
    projectId: serviceAccount.project_id,
    keyFilename: serviceAccountPath,
    credentials: {
        client_email: serviceAccount.client_email,
        private_key: serviceAccount.private_key
    },
});

If someone can help, it would be great.

Yes, it will work. Usually (!?) the only difference between creating Cloud service clients locally and on a compute service is that the Project ID isn't detected locally. As long as you set the Project ID correctly (!?) in the Logging constructor, this will work. Are your credentials the same when running locally|deployed? Is the Project ID being determined|set correctly?

yes i mean this is the same project, so the service account file should work. I just notice that there is this line in the emulator compilation :
'⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: database, hosting, storage, dataconnect'.
I don't no if the logging is affected by 'dataconnect' or something. Or if there is a specific authorisation to add from GCP. What do you mean by 'Are your credentials the same when running locally|deployed?' ?

You said that when you deployed the function, cloud logging works. What Service Account is the function using when it's deployed? If you use the same Service Account when running locally as long as you're additionally setting the correct Project ID in the constructor, it will work. I know this because I tried it. So, you're either using a different Service Account with insufficient permissions to write logs and/or you're incorrectly setting the Project ID

Ok i just try with all my service acc even with the Google service account that have all the rights and the one that deploy the cloud function, still don't work. Even if I write the project_id hard. There is the simple code : https://github.com/YaLazreq/logging-debug/blob/main/index.js
If you have the code you tried it would be great if you showed it to me

I used the Cloud Logging sample and ran it locally.
